# Consulta para restar horas en sql

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos,

[image: fichaje]

Se van añadiendo registros de fichajes de los trabajadores, y necesito crear una nueva tabla, donde aparezcan el Nombre, el CBA, la fecha y el CDAL. Además, en una sola línea, y en vez de la hora y minutos, una nueva columna que salga calculada la resta entre el fichaje de salida y el de entrada.
No hay ningún indicador si es fichaje de entrada o de salida, habría que hacerlo restando las horas, por ejemplo 18:02 - 13:49.

Además, me encuentro también con el problema con lo que hacen turno de noche, que entran por ejemplo el día 01/09 a las 22:00 y salen el día 02/09 a las 06:00.

¿Podríais echarme una mano de como realizarlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Lo último: qué motor de BD estás usando? Pon siempre la etiqueta correspondiente

Answer (score 0):

No puedo hacer la consulta de manera correcta ya que no tengo la estructura de la tabla, pero espero que lo siguiente te pueda servir:
con esta query deberás hacer sub consultas para obtener los valores de fecha inicio y fecha fin de x trabajador

```
SELECT 
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
          /*FECHA INICIO TURNO*/
          cast(concat("2020" , "-" , "09" , "-" , "21" , " " , "22" , ":" , "55") as datetime),
          /*FECHA FIN TURNO*/
          cast(concat("2020" , "-" , "09" , "-" , "22" , " " , "07" , ":" , "55") as datetime)
         )) AS "Horas y Minutos Trabajados"
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Estás usando sintaxis que parece ser de Oracle, pero la imagen de la pregunta se asemeja más a SQL Server. Te aconsejo no responder a menos de que haya un claro indicio del RDBMS que se está usando.

Comment: Tal y como ha comentado Luis, la base de datos está en SQL Server. La estructura de la base de datos es la siguiente:                                             `CBA         char(20) 
Dia           smallint 
Mes         smallint 
Anyo int 
Hora smallint
Minuto smallint 
CDAH smallint 
CDAL smallint 
SUMA int 
VALOR nvarchar(50) 
NumReloj nvarchar(3) 
IdUsu int 
IdReg bigint `